# Can vstest.console filter tests by all matched traits?

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, vstest.console

As documented [on this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx), `vstest.console`can filter tests to run by traits. For example, a sample `vstest.console` command might look as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "C:\mytest.dll" /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=traitA|TestCategory=traitB|traitN" /logger:trx
```

Actually, the whole article says that multiple traits will be provided using the following syntax:

```
<Expression> is of the format <property>=<value>[|<Expression>].
```

My issue is when you provide more than a trait, tests are filtered using a logical *or* and official documentation says nothing about how to filter tests that match **all given traits**.

Comment: if you want to provide the question and answer you can make the question as Community wiki

Comment: @HakamFostok Why, SO encourage providing both the Q and A during the Q&A creation.

Comment: yes, provide a question and answer, this may be helpful for other. I do NOT have a problem with this, I just suggested to mark the question as community wiki.

Comment: @HakamFostok I don't see the whole button to protect this Q&A as community wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided article has **an undocumented expression format**. If you use `&` instead of `|` to provide multiple *traits*, **you're going to filter tests which match all given traits.**

For example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "C:\mytest.dll" /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=traitA&TestCategory=traitB&traitN" /logger:trx
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that option is missing from the MSDN Page.
However it is indeed mentioned in the tool itself.
In particular look for the /TestCaseFilter switch from the output of running ***vstest.console.exe /?***

Thank you for reporting this.

Comment: You're welcome, BTW I believe that this should be a comment instead of an answer :\